# Error while using comm command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a bash script in which I am using comm command, I keep getting the error

```
san.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
san.sh: line 12: `    comm < (grep -r --include "collect.xml" "mean enabled=\"true\"" /opt/Test/test1 | grep -v bak | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | sort -u)  < (cat /etc/bruce/wayne/mansion.ini  | grep LogType | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sort -u)'

comm < (grep -r --include "collect.xml" "mean enabled=\"true\"" /opt/Test/test1 | grep -v bak | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | sort -u)  < (cat /etc/bruce/wayne/mansion.ini  | grep Type | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sort -u)
```

If I where to run the command in the terminal I get the desired output only in the script does it through this error :(

[image: Results after removing spacing issue]

Comment: ok, 1) [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), it makes it harder for the readers to copypaste the code to study it, and the code blocks on SE have (at least some sort of) syntax highlighting, which can help find issues. Also esp. that blue on black in your screenshot is quite hard to read, 2) if you have a complex command causing problems, simplify it to remove the unnecessary stuff, e.g. `comm <(echo foo) <(echo bar)` would be enough here to trigger the syntax error.

Comment: 3) you're running the script with `sh`, not `bash`. From the error message it looks like your `sh` is Bash, but in `sh` mode it doesn't support process substitutions, which is why you get the error. Run the scripts with `bash`, or add the execute permission and run them as `./san.sh` so that the hashbang applies.

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu
My mistake was after correct the spacing issue pointed out by choroba I did not execute the script as bash as you rightly pointed out. After running the script with ./ it worked. 
I am not sure if I can mark two comments as answer. I do not see an option for it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process substitution symbol `<(` should be written without a space (both of them).

Comment: I did try to remove the space but now it shows as "No such file or directory"
`comm<(grep -r --include "collect.xml" "mean enabled=\"true\"" /opt/Test/test1 | grep -v bak | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | sort -u)<(cat /etc/bruce/wayne/mansion.ini  | grep Type | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sort -u)`

If I just remove

Comment: If I just remove a space between two command and not after comm command I get the old error as in description
**san.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
san.sh: line 12: `    c**
`comm <(grep -r --include "collect.xml" "mean enabled=\"true\"" /opt/Test/test1 | grep -v bak | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | sort -u)<(cat /etc/bruce/wayne/mansion.ini  | grep Type | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sort -u)`

Comment: The `<(` shouldn't have a space inside. All other spaces were OK.

Comment: i.e., use `comm <(...) <(...)`. Note that in some cases you also need the redirection operator, in addition to the process substitution, and there you do need a space between the `<`/`>` and the `<(`/`>(`, e.g. `echo foo > >(cat -n)`

Comment: :( This is the script and it is not working but able to see the results if entered n the terminal
`#!/bin/bash
comm <(grep -r --include "collect.xml" "mean enabled=\"true\"" /opt/Test/test1 | grep -v bak | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | sort -u) <(cat /etc/bruce/wayne/mansion.ini  | grep Type | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sort -u)`
**san.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token (' san.sh: line 12:  c comm <(grep -r --include "collect.xml" "mean enabled=\"true\"" /opt/Test/test1 | grep -v bak | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | sort -u)<(cat /etc/bruce/wayne/mansion.ini  | grep Type | cut -d "=" -f 2 | sort -u)**

Comment: A space missing between `)` and `<(`.

Comment: I am sorry all. I did try all spacing suggestions still keep getting the same error. I was not able to attach a screenshot here so attached it in the description. I tried four different ways of spacing and all had the same result.

Comment: Don't use `sh` to run the script. It might run the script in `dash` or whatever else instead of `bash`.